# How to check if element exixts in a array of a especific document in mongoose / mongo db?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, find

look, I have  this schema:

```js
_id: 'id'
info: {
   array: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

I want to check something like this:

```js
doc = schema.find({ _id: 'id' });
if ( doc.info.array.includes('a') ) //returning true
```

I don't know how to make that. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to check this but here are a few:

```js
var data = schema.find({
  _id: "id",
  array: {
    $in: ["a"]
  },
});

if (!data) {
  return false;
}
return true
```

Another way is by:

```js
var data = schema.find({
  _id: "id",
  array: {
    $in: ["a"]
  },
}).count();

if (data == 0) {
  return false;
}
return true
```